# Reading from one table to get a field and then using that field info to query and get information from another field takes a LONG time

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql, ado.net

I am writing a desktop application that connects to a MySQl database on a remote server.
I have two tables in a MySQL database.

One Table called Client contains the Contacts Id and other basic contact information.

The other table is called Property and contains the property type and address information and also has a Client_Id field that is the same as the Id field in the Client table.

Currently I open a connection to the database.

Then I use a Select query to get a List from the Property table for all the properties whose field call PropertyType = 'House'.

Then I take that List and enumerate through it using ANOTHER SELECT query that gets each Client based on their Id that natched the Id in the list.

Then I close the connection.
So I am only opening and closing the connection one time.

This takes a long time for just 400 records, I am just learning mySQL and am sure there is a better way. Can anyone offer any advice as to how I would query a table to get all the fields that match a certain criteria and then use a filed (Client_Id) to search another table to get clients based up their Id matching the Client_Id?

Comment: can you post the `schema` of your table?

Comment: Have you looked at using a subquery in your SQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which data you want to see, try something like:

```
select p.address, c.name, c.phone
from Property p
join Clients c on p.client_id = c.id
where p.PropertyType = 'House'
```

Comment: That sort of did the trick! 
Here is what I ended up using by doing a little research before I saw this answer. But this answers overall path worked for me!

"SELECT * FROM Client INNER JOIN Property ON Client.Id = Property.Lead_Id WHERE Property.PropertyType = 'House'"

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce that to a single Query with something like

```
SELECT * FROM Client WHERE Client_id IN (SELECT Client_id FROM Property WHERE PropertyType='House');
```

Additionally make sure, you have all your indices in place.

Comment: when I run that I get an error Unknown column 'Client_Id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'
I made sure that I do have that column in the Property table

Comment: Test the subquery on its own: SELECT Client_id FROM Property WHERE PropertyType='House'